# Error "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater" While uploading on IIS

Tags: oracle9i, oracleclient, system.data.oracleclient

I'm Using ASP.Net With oracle 9i database,when i trying to upload project on iis server,it gives me error like "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater" is there any need of installing client software or any other solution on that?
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Why do you use a 15 years(!) old Oracle version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ADO.NET (i.e. `System.Data.OracleClient`) requires an Oracle client to be installed, otherwise it does not work.